# FIRPhoneAuthProvider providerWithAuth not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase in ios project , there I used 
firebase  authentication with phone number . `FIRPhoneAuthProvider providerWithAuth` I am using

but getting error

> **FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_WEB_CONTEXT_ALREADY_PRESENTED, error**

```
[[FIRPhoneAuthProvider providerWithAuth:[FIRAuth authWithApp:firApp]] verifyPhoneNumber:phoneNumber UIDelegate:nil completion:^(
      NSString *_Nullable verificationID,
      NSError *_Nullable error)
 {
    if (error) {
     // getting error here 
    } else {
      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [defaults setObject:verificationID forKey:@"authVerificationID"];

    }
  }];
```

error is

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17057 "User interaction is still ongoing, another view cannot be presented." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User interaction is still ongoing, another view cannot be presented., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_WEB_CONTEXT_ALREADY_PRESENTED}




 pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.3.0'
```

other question on react native , its this on native ios .